Can glueballs and bosons survive indefinetely in space (forming structures)?
I have been recently interested in looking for possible structures (ranging from clumped structures like "stars" to diffuse clouds of gas or halos) made from standard model-particles other than protons, electrons and neutrons.
One possibility that I've read is that there may be glueballs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball) forming such structures (which some physicists have argued to find evidence for them: https://bigthink.com/starts-with-a-bang/new-particle-first-glueball/) or that bosons such as the mesons can form condensates and “gas”.
I have 3 questions about this:
Could structures (like diffuse clouds of these particles or halos) made from these particles survive indefinetely in the universe?
Which possibility is more grounded?
Are there any other particles from the standard model that could form these structures?


Can <…> survive indefinitely in space (forming structures)?

No, in a universe with positive cosmological constant. Whatever the mechanism is for formation of a composite object (that you called “structure”) from multiple smaller parts, such object would generically be unstable in a universe with a positive cosmological constant against fragmentation through tunneling toward cosmic horizon.
For example, if the composite object contains a gravitationally bound particle in a non-relativistic  motion outside the main part of that object, then pseudo-Newtonian potential for such motion in the presence of cosmological constant is
$$ V_\text{dS}=-\frac{GM}r- \frac{\Lambda c^2 r^2}6.$$
But if $V<0$ and $\Lambda>0$ then an allowed range of classical motion in addition to a usual region of bound orbits near the origin includes also a region of unbound motion at large $r$ corresponding to a particle falling toward cosmic horizon. So in quantum theory a bound state localized near the origin would be unstable: particle can tunnel through the potential barrier toward the region of unbound motion.
Qualitatively the same thing would happen for other types of composite objects. Its precise nature does not matter: it can be a set of weakly interacting gravitationally bound particles (neutrino halos, boson stars etc.), its binding mechanism can be non-gravitational (electromagnetic, nuclear forces etc.) or something else entirely. But if such object can be fragmented by transferring a finite amount of energy, then it can also spontaneously decay in  the presence of cosmic horizon. Of course, since this decay mechanism involves tunneling through cosmologically significant distances, it can become significant only if other mechanisms of decay are absent and the lifetimes of objects for which this effect is the main channel of decay can be much, much longer than other characteristic timescales of the distant future (such as lifetime of supermassive black  holes).
Of course, we do not know presently if the observed accelerating expansion of the Universe is due to cosmological constant or some other mechanism, so the answer is strongly depend on the type of a model and what distant future that model would predict.

I have a few questions about this: 1. Even in this scenario will the composite object be destined to disappear? I mean, even if some particles get unbound from it, could they return to be gravitationally bounded again? 2. Would this also happen for black holes (ignoring evaporation by hawking radiation)? 3. You say that generally all composite objects are unstable in a universe with a cosmological constant, but as it is "generally" the case, does that mean that there are exceptions? @A.V.S.

@vengaq I mean, even if some particles get unbound from it, could they return to be gravitationally bounded again? Sure, this would be just like thermodynamic fluctuation that spontaneously reassemble a broken glass vase, it could happen. In essence, cosmic horizon has its own Hawking radiation, and it can in principle emit precisely what is needed to reassemble your bose-condensate-star/neutrino halo/q-ball-structure but the probability that it would happen in any given unit of time is extremely tiny.

Would this also happen for black holes… Yes, and this smoothly meshes with Hawkins radiation, so you cannot ignore it, even if you were able to suppress perturbative modes of Hawking radiation, tunneling to cosmic horizon will be yet another decay channel.

does that mean that there are exceptions? I do not know. Ultimately the question is similar to that one: “Can God create a rock so big that He cannot lift it?” If you believe in unitarity of quantum mechanics the answer would be negative.

Thank you. In this paper by Sean Carroll (arxiv.org/abs/1405.0298) he argues that all radiation and particles would leave the cosmological horizon leaving the universe as a "dead" universe with essentially nothing else. Even if that is true, and applying it to my question, what would happen if the bound particles "leave" the horizon? Could they become gravitationally bounded again but in another Hubble volume? And finally, returning to my OP, are long-lasting composite objects made by glueballs or boson particles "gas" possible? @A.V.S.

Could they become gravitationally bounded again but in another Hubble volume? Within traditional framework of QFTCS this would be similar to any other quantum fluctuation: such probability is nonzero but very small (for some fixed Hubble volume per unit of time) but the number of such volumes grows exponentially with time in a universe with positive cosmological constant, so eventually existence of any fluctuation, however unlikely, somewhere becomes inevitable.

finally, returning to my OP, are long-lasting composite objects made by glueballs or boson particles "gas" possible they has not been ruled out, that is all that could be said yet. Note, that stuff beyond standard model may also come with its own mechanisms of decay.

but glueballs and boson-made "gas" clouds would be made by standard model particles, and these do not decay in principle. Is this right? @A.V.S.
